# Dependency problems between php 5.3 and php 5.6

Tags: php, centos

Originally I had php 5.3 installed in my centos machine (version 6.4) .. however I upgraded the version of php to be 5.6 using these commands lines :

```
yum remove php-common
yum install php56w
yum install php56w-mysql
yum install php56w-common
yum install php56w-pdo
yum install php56w-opcache
```

Actually when I run php -v it gives me : 5.6.

However when I'm trying to install the package php-devel:

```
sudo yum install php-devel --skip-broken
```

it gives me :

```
Packages skipped because of dependency problems:
    php-5.3.3-47.el6.x86_64 from base
    php-cli-5.3.3-47.el6.x86_64 from base
    php-common-5.3.3-47.el6.x86_64 from base
    php-devel-5.3.3-47.el6.x86_64 from base
```

How may I correct this dependency problem ?

Thanks

Comment: did you try `sudo yum install php56w-devel` ?

Comment: Yes :) thats work fine :) thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should install the 5.6 version of php-devel.

```
sudo yum install php56w-devel
```

On this link you can see the list of packages for centos and php5.6 on the "packages" section:

> https://webtatic.com/packages/php56/